# Retrieve number of views in a scrollview

Tags: uiscrollview, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I am currently trying to write some automated tests within instruments and am having a bit of an issue, is it possible to retrieve the number of views/panes in a scrollView so that I can say, if more than one view, scrollRight() for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count = scrollview.subviews.count;

if ( count > 1 ) 
{
.....
}
```

??

EDIT:

You will need to get a reference to the view you are looking for. This will be done by iterating through your windows subview collection. In objective-C it would be something like this:

```
 NSInteger count = 0;
 for ( UIView *view in self.window.subviews )
 {
     if([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
     {
          count = (UIScrollView *) view.subviews.count;
     }

 }
```

Comment: Just tried the above and am getting a parse error - have tried the following too with no luck:`int count = frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].count; int count = frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].subviews.count; int count = frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollview.subviews.count;`

Comment: See above edit.. so you need to search in the mainWindow subview collection for you scrollview first

Comment: Thanks! got it working now - I ended up doing a count of title elements to give me the total number of views